# Вынесение переменой за функцию

Tags: javascript, node.js, функции, переменные

Есть функция из которой нужно выделить переменную

```
return { // Массив из функций 
  func: function(){
    someFunction(function(variable){
      // Выделит переменную variable
    })
    return variable; // Возвращаем переменную
  }
}
```

Comment: что значит _выделить_?

Comment: Вынести за функцию.

Comment: Вынести прямо в коде? Что бы переменная была видна после выполнения функции? Или что?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Я задал несколько вопросов, на какой вы ответили?

Comment: Вынести прямо в коде? Что бы переменная была видна после выполнения функции? Или что? На этот

Comment: @ThisMan респект за терпение)

Answer (score 1):

```
let variable;

someFunction(function(){
  // variable доступна тут
})
```

Comment: Почему то не работает ИМЕННО В МОЕМ КОДЕ. Ну а на jsfiddle все работает, сейчас сделаю правку может быть это поможет

Comment: @NikitaShamberger код ваш в вопрос тогда вставьте, что бы все могли посмотреть

Comment: Уже сделал. Можете посмотреть. Буду очень благодарен если поможите

Comment: а что ваш код делает? он какой-то неполный

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/orvcaf3z/6/